# Android App running fine via debugging installation but crashes in case of created app(android-debug.apk)

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-runtime

Application is crashing when apk is created and installed in my phone. But works fine when is run with usb debugging.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
            at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:165)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22344)
            at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
            at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22344)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6704)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
            at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
```

Tried changing build Versions
no code error

**Please Help!!!**

**logcat** [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Di0bJ1oyM7yX1-oqTLNy5cbVKGmNBqUU)

link to [MainActivity.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ghDt_TjpAc-COdo8iMdf2-656FpBuvCY)

link to [HomeFragment.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z4nOVFbixjWCY-jFEUwqPBP5Fg7VvbUv)

link to [Manifest](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jQKsvtvKVi17eT1BD5q9fhvQXsqVCUkZ)

link to [build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11HIKu75p__k1JtgXPnIkgmfIqLZ9i-sF)

Comment: Have you tried creating signed apk and then installing it in your phone?

Comment: Give a look at your proguard file (btw, link the proguard file in the question), it may be removing those classes, also, take a look at this issue https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out a few things:

1. Make sure that your `items` and `facility_items` classes are public. If they are inner classes then make them static.
2. Generate a signed apk and then install it in your device and run it.

See a similar issue here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46

Hope this helps